# iTunes Connect not showing anything under "App Store Status"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I released a second version of my app through iTunes Connect and nothing is showing under App Store Status. Shouldn't I at lease see "Waiting for review" or " In review"? Did something go wrong or this is normal
[image]

Comment: Did you actually clicked "Submit for review" in your version's page ?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this? I have the same problem, i dont need to update meta data, just update current version. I cant see any buttons, they are all greyed out.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is correct.

This is true until you select a build to be reviewed in the "App Store" tab

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Apple is confusing in certain areas.**

Please follow the below steps

1. Please click on "+ Version or Platform"

[image]

2. Add a build number
3. And, here you are - with the 'prepare for submission' screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in 2018, there's a "+ version of platform" button at the bottom left sidebar in the App Store tab

[image]